# Autocorrelation plot intuitive

Tags: python, statistics, autocorrelation

I am analyzing a time series dataset and I used `seasonal_decompose` function in `statsmodel` library to obtain trend and seasonal behavior. I obtained the autocorrelation plot and the decomposition of the time-series provided should provide a “remainder” component that should be uncorrelated. By observing the autocorrelation plot how do we say that auto-correlation function indicate that the remainder is indeed uncorrelated?

I am attaching the code I used to obtain autocorrelation plot and the plot obtained.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))
plot_acf(data, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[Autocorrelation_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syfzg.png)

Answer (score 0):

if the results of auto correlation are close to zero then the features not not correlated.  I use lag of 40, but you will need to adjust this value dependant on your data.

```
plt.clf()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')
fig = tsaplots.plot_acf(df['value'], lags=40,ax=ax)
plt.show()
print('values close to 1 are showing strong positive correlation. The blue regions are showing areas of uncertainty')
```